# Joint density of transformation

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $X, Y$ be two independent exponential random variables, and let $U = \frac{X}{Y}, V = X + Y$.

I am trying to prove that $U$ and $V$ are independent, so I computed their individual densities which yield $f_U(t) = \frac{ab}{(a t + b)^2}, f_V(t) = \frac{ab}{a +b}\left(e^{-bt}-e^{-at}\right)$, where $a,b$ are the parameters of $X$ and $Y$.

How do I compute their joint density, and if it's not possible, is there any other way to prove independence?

Comment: You can find the joint distribution $f_{U, V}$ by using inverse transformation theorem for random vector $(U, V)$. Here's a link of an lecture note about this: http://ece-research.unm.edu/bsanthan/ece340/note1.pdf

Comment: You can also show that $\Bbb P(U>t,V>t)=\Bbb P(U>t)\,\Bbb P(V>t)$ for all $t>0$.